# Como obtengo un elemento con pseudoelemento a travez de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy usando esto:

```
document.querySelector("div::before");
```

Para tratar de seleccionar esto:

```
div::before {
  
}
```

Comment: Puedes obtener el elemento, pero no el **pseudoelemento**, porque no es un elemento independiente; revisa [estas notas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#notes). ¿Para qué quieres obtener el pseudoelemento? Edita la pregunta y trata de ser muy específico en lo que quieres lograr, seguramente es posible asignado clases CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar utilizando un **Window.getComputedStyle**.
[Puedes ver la documentación en este enlace.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Tu codigo deberia quedar asi

```
const element = document.querySelector('div');
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element,':before')
```

Otro ejemplo mas directo que puedes implementar

```
window.getComputedStyle(
document.querySelector('div'), ':before');
```